# How to convert an RDD into a 2d array in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am using Apache Spark for a project. I have a `DataFrame`. I have been able to convert it into an `RDD`. I need to convert it into a *2d array*. Below is the code that I have written. What should I do next?

```
val x: List[List[String]] = df.select(columnNames(0), (columnNames.drop(1): _*)).rdd.collect()
```

Here *df* is `DataFrame`.

Comment: Just `.collect()`, if I understand your question correctly. `def
collect(): Array[T]
Return an array that contains all of the elements in this RDD.`

Comment: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 required: scala.collection.mutable.List[List[String]]

Comment: I am getting this error.

Comment: Edit your question to include the code that gives the error. You're not calling `collect` on a RDD, I'm guessing.

Comment: No, I am using collect on RDD.

Comment: What do you think your select expression does, just to be sure ?

Comment: I think it gives me a new Dataframe.

Comment: Post your code. Or we're just guessing. I think it's what you're doing after the collect that's the problem - you're doing something that requires al list, but you've got an Array of Rows. Probably you want `.collect().map(_.toSeq)`? But, seriously, ,how do you expect us to work out what the error is without code?

Comment: `List[List[String]] `. But the return value of `collect` is an Array. Why do you expect this to work?

Comment: what about `columnNames(0), (columnNames.drop(1): _*)` ? For me this means you want to select all the column of the dataframe. This is what you want to do ?

Comment: x = df.select(columnNames(0), (columnNames.drop(1): _*)).rdd.collect().toList.map(row => row.toSeq.map(v => v.asInstanceOf[String]).toList)


This is what I have done. Is this alright.

Comment: @eliasah, yes, that is what I want to do.

Comment: Your columns have just StringType data ?

Comment: It can be string or number. I am trying to convert them all to String

Comment: unfortunately if there is two types, you'll need to convert 1 by 1 or perform a pattern matching

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102206/discussion-between-eliasah-and-eddard-stark).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussing your problem in the chat, here is the solution :

```
val x : List[List[String]] = df.select(columnNames.head, columnNames.tail: _*).
                             rdd.map{ case r : Row => 
                               Row(r.getAs[Long](0).toString,r.getAs[Long](1).toString,r.getAs[String](2)).toSeq.map(v => v.asInstanceOf[String]).toList
                             }.collect.toList
```

Since I don't have a view on the actually data, remember that this is an example, you can get the columns as you wish by it's field name.
example : `r.getAs[String]("column1")`

Another solution, which I'm not very fan of is :

```
val x : List[List[String]] = df.select(columnNames.head, columnNames.tail: _*).
                             rdd.map{ case r : Row => 
                               r.mkString(",").split(",").toList
                             }.collect.toList
```